# Is there an app which graphs arbitrary tag volume over time?

Tags: discussion, app-request

Has anyone made an app which displays a graph of question volume for any *arbitrary* tag? I know that "analytics overflow" reports some of this info for popular (top 70 or something?) tags, but I think it would actually be more interesting to see this for less popular tags, for instance to see fast rising fringe topics. I don't think you can do this with that app, <strike>plus I don't think there is a graph, is there?</strike> There is I just didn't see it when I first visited the page

http://popacular.com/analyticsoverflow/?site=so&tag=clojure

Is there any other app that does this? I want to see something like, past 6 mos activity on any tag, preferably in a line graph.

Thanks!

ETA btw I hope this kind of question is ok, it seemed like there were some other "is there an app that ..." questions.

Comment: Please remove the [app] tag from this question. See [this link](http://stackapps.com/tags/app/info) for more.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

Well I thought it wouldn't be too hard to make this so I did:

http://stackovergraph.heroku.com/

It's pretty rough around the edges but I'll add some stuff over the weekend.